# I cannot run pip anymore

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, pyopenssl

So when I am trying to execute "$ python3 -m pip" on my linux I have this error:

```
python3 -m pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    vendored("requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-22.1.0-py3.9.egg/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-22.1.0-py3.9.egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-22.1.0-py3.9.egg/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3224, in <module>
TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

I have the same error when I run it like "$ pip" as user, it only works when I run it as sudo "$ sudo python3 -m pip" or "$ sudo pip". I tried to solve the problem myself by install pyopenssl myself with the latest version but it still dont works. Can someone solve this? Thx

Comment: I also uninstalled and reinstalled pip but it stillz dont work

Comment: Have you considered removing `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-22.1.0-py3.9.egg` ?  That doesn't seem to belong to the rest of your python distribution, given its location...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+deprecated+got+an+unexpected+keyword+argument+name

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found out that the same issue was encountered by many other people on this thread:
[Answer](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/1154)

So the solution was to uninstall pyOpenSSL with
"$ sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pyOpenSSL"

I don't think there is another solution. Need to wait for the next update of the pyOpenSSL package and pray for the compatibility issue to get corrected.